# Lazy load making pages freeze/load very slow on IE?

Tags: internet-explorer, drupal, lazy-loading

I'm working on a Drupal site that had lazy load implemented into it because it is very image heavy. The feature works on every browser but IE, in which the page periodically freezes when scrolling down to see images due to a "long running script".

It seems like this is something of a known issue, but I can't seem to find a conclusive fix for the problem. Does anyone know if there is a known-workaround, or is this still a case-by-case fix?

Answer (score 0):

I assume you are using a lazyloader like jquery unveil. This plugin is known to be very lightweight, but also very resource intensive/inefficient.

You can change the lazyloading script to something more performant.

I'm the developer of https://github.com/aFarkas/lazysizes which shouldn't cause performance problems. Supported browsers: https://github.com/aFarkas/lazysizes#browser-support

Answer (score 0):

If you also need **IE8** support, I suggest you to use [justlazy](http://fhopeman.github.io/justlazy), which is very lightweight and doesn't use jQuery.

It's very easy to use:

**1. Define placeholder of your choice**

```html
<span data-src="default/image" data-alt="some alt text"
      class="justlazy-placeholder">
</span>
```

**2. Register lazy loading of placeholder(s)**

```js
Justlazy.registerLazyLoadByClass("justlazy-placeholder");
```

There are some options available and you can SEO optimize your placeholder due to use an img as placeholder.